# Finding jQuery autocomplete plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I went through many autocomplete plugins, but have not found the right one.

My JSON response looks like:

```
[
{ mode: 'link', url : 'http://aaa.com', name: 'AAA', img: 'http://aa.com/a.gif' },
{ mode: 'link', url : 'http://bbb.com', name: 'BBB', img: 'http://aa.com/b.gif' },
{ mode: 'link', url : 'http://ccc.com', name: 'CCC', img: 'http://aa.com/c.gif' },
]
```

What I need:

- Not jQueryUI :)
- Can selecte only one option (don't need `Facebook`-style autocomplete)
- I need event `onSelect` fired from `drop-down-list` to change page's location to `json's` `url` property.
- I need to format `drop-down-list`, based on own `json` data. For example, I need to draw images and so on... (`img` property from `json`)

Anybody knows a jQuery plugin, that fits these requirements?

P.S.
`jQuery TokenInput` http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/ is very good, but I don't need that many options.

Comment: Where does the standard jQuery UI Autocomplete not meet your requirements -> http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: How can I format dropdown list? Does it have events `onSelect`? In documentation I didn't found.

Comment: go to the page i linked - half way down the page there are tabs - 1 for events - you will find the 'select' event .... then there is a theming tab - you will find how to style it there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this  http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

Answer (score 0):

I guess [EasyAutocomplete](http://easyautocomplete.com) is a plugin for you. It matches all of yours requirements, plus it can a lot more. It's well documented in the guide section and it has prepared couple of examples, that shows how it works.